# Exclude Packages, Files, and Classes from Cobertura Jenkins report?

Tags: jenkins, cobertura

I'm trying to get Cobertura code coverage reports integrated into Jenkins for my company's AngularJS project. It's working, however, packages files and classes with es5 AngularJS project are always 100%. What I'm more focused on obviously, are the methods lines and conditionals.

Since the first 3 metrics are always 100% the graph leaves little to be desired as I can't zoom in close enough to notice slight changes in the metrics.

**Is there a way to exclude Packages, Files, and Classes from the report?**

[image]

Comment: I don't think, there is any way to do so. Why would you compare little bars lengths instead of numbers anyway?

Comment: The graph is the only thing that's displayed on the main project page. also, it can be confusing to non-technical folks, just trying to clean things up a bit.